# Fetch id of clicked element using .live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per suggestions i changed my code to below

```
<dl id="accRegion">
<#list command.instruments as instrType>            
<dt ><a class="red">${instrType}</a></dt>
<dd >
    <#list command.logDates as logDate>
        <div id="${instrType}"><a class="orange">${logDate}</a></dt>
    </#list>
</dd>
</#list>
```

but it still gets me the id of first element instead of the clicked one. **Also, this dl is an accordion.**

Here is the generated html fragment

```
<dl id="accRegion">
<dt ><a class="red">Stocks</a></dt>
<dd >
        <div id="Stocks"><a class="orange">2011-05-31</a></dt>
</dd>
<dt ><a class="red">Futures</a></dt>

<dd >
        <div id="Futures"><a class="orange">2011-05-31</a></dt>
</dd>
```

Trying below method

```
    $("#accRegion div").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: That will definitely get you the "id" value of the clicked element. Note that your code is broken - you're using the same "id" value for every `<dd>` element, which can cause problems.

Comment: Also, a `<dl>` with nothing but `<dt>` elements in it doesn't really make a lot of sense.  Maybe it should be a `<ul>` with a list of `<li>` elements.

Comment: @Pointy: That is actually the answer (I think). The question was: *Function below gets me the id of the first element in the list and not the clicked one* . There is only one ID, though I'm not sure which list he is talking about (as they seem to be nested).

Comment: this will give the id of the <dt id="${}instrType"

Comment: @Felix Kling - ah yes, I see - that variable is the loop var from the *outer* loop, not the one that generates the `<dt>` elements.

Comment: Its always getting me the value of first ${instrType} in the list and not the one for clicked element. I think having same id doesnt cause problem because this works for me at other places. But in those cases list is loaded on page load whereas this one is generated by Ajax call.

Comment: @Shikha: No two elements on the same page should ever have the same ID.

Comment: @Shikha - all the `<dt>` elements in the list will have exactly the same "id".  Do a "view source" on your page so that you can see for yourself.

Comment: @Shikha: Think about it. You want the ID of the clicked element and you get only the one of the first element... but **every** element has the same ID as the first element... there is no way to tell whether the first one or another one was clicked...

Comment: @Shikha: Is `${instrType}` a dynamically-generated and _unique_ ID, or not? That information is key to finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: I changed my code to this but it still gets me the if of first element instead of the clicked one. <dl id="accRegion">
 <#list command.instruments as instrType>   
 <dt ><a class="red">${instrType}</a></dt>
 <dd >
  <#list command.logDates as logDate>
   <div id="${instrType}"><a class="orange">${logDate}</a></dt>
  </#list>
 </dd>
 </#list>
</dl>

Comment: I have figured out that this problem happens only when the lists are loaded by Ajax call. The same code works perfectly well if i load it on initial page load instead of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you are using same `id` multiple times on a page ;whereas its is necessary that `id` must be **unique** on a pages; that's your main problem. and there is also alternative method of `attr` in jQuery v1.6.Yu can use [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#accRegion dd dt").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).prop("id"));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/w8ZDc/)**

Comment: This will make no difference at all.

Comment: @pointy she just ask  any different way; i do it; nothing else; `ID` must be unique that has been tod her already

Comment: The problem actually is: *Function below gets me the id of the first element in the list and not the clicked one*

Comment: Why not simply alert `this.id` ?

Comment: bcoz she is using same `id` multiple times;whereas we all know that `id` must be unique on a page

Comment: I think you missed the point of my comment.  `$(this).prop('id')` constructs a jQuery object from the element `this` then uses jQuery to get the `id` property, but the `id` property already exists on `this` without the need for a jQuery object.  None of which answers the problem, though ;)

Comment: @Flexi i have updated my answer with ur suggestion as well as @Town's too

Comment: @diEcho: that won't work now - you're missing the `$`.  Either `$(this).prop('id')` (less efficient) or `this.id` (native and more efficient).

Comment: @Town; sorry i m just confued too much today; Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#accRegion dd dt").live('click',function(e){
    alert($(e.currentTarget).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work either. Still gets the first element in the list.

Comment: @Shikha: How can you possibly tell it's getting the first element when all the elements have the same ID? See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/T4Qnc/) for what happens if you have different IDs.

Comment: @Shikha: The solution is to use different IDs for the elements. Point.